# why is my uialertview being dismissed on applicationdidbecomeActive every other time I resume?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

I'm working on a cocos2d game and im using a uialertview for the pause screen, for some reason when i exit out using the home button and then re enter the app the uialertview is dismissed everyother time i exit and relaunch. the uialertview is shown everytime the user exits or a call comes in. the other thing that is weird is that when the alert view is dismissed the darkness around the edges is not present.

any idea how or why this would be dismissed without the user clicking anything.

Not sure if this helps but the game itself does not resume when the alert is dismissed, however your touch events are being recieved by cocos2d becuase when you resume the game you can see the stuff you did while it was paused now shown after a real resume. I know this is vague but I though if anyone might have had this issue before they may know what I'm talking about.

thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug
there are some workarounds here

[UIAlertViewDelegate method didDismissWithButtonIndex gets called while the phone is sleeping/locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190999/uialertviewdelegate-method-diddismisswithbuttonindex-gets-called-while-the-phone)